# Java: try-catch vs if-else for initialization: performance

Tags: java, if-statement, initialization, try-catch

I've heard it's a sin to use try-catch for anything that might be expected to happen in normal program flow, and that one should use if-else instead.

But, what about the case where we want to use it for initialization (an event that happens once and once only).  You may want this when you initialization depends on the first incoming data, as in the following example:

```
class RunningVectorSum{

    double[] running_sum;

    public double[] add(double vec[]){

        try{
            for (int i=0; i<running_sum.length; i++)
                running_sum[i]+=vec[i];
        }
        catch(NullPointerException ex){
            running_sum = new double[vec.length];
            for (int i=0; i<running_sum.length; i++)
                running_sum[i] = vec[i];
        }
        return running_sum;
    }
}
```

In this case, should it be faster in the long run to use the try-catch vs using:

```
    public double[] add(double vec[]){
        if (running_sum==null)
            running_sum = new double[vec.length];
        for (int i=0; i<running_sum.length; i++)
            running_sum[i]+=vec[i];
        return running_sum;
    }
```

instead?

edit: Things I'm aware of:

- Yes in this particular example, there's a possible problem if vec has a varying length
- Yes I know this is a terrible sin.

Things I'm not aware of:

- Why is it such a terrible sin?
- Is it faster to always pass through a try (except once, which amortizes to nothing) than it is to always pass through an if(condition)

Comment: Throwing exceptions has a cost and I'm probably sure using an `if` is both clearer and faster.

Comment: Catching a `NullPointerException` when you could just check for `null` is both convoluted and slow. Why would you ever do this? The modern Java 8 solution would be to use `Optional`...

Comment: `catch(NullPointerException ex)` - waaaaaaaaaaaaaargh. That is a VERY big NONO.

Comment: Alright alright why is it such a NONO?

Comment: @Peter because it's unclear. It's slow. It's unnecessary. And in this particular case it clearly violates DRY.

Comment: Tries and catches and throws are essentially always going to be slower than doing a simple if statement.

Comment: ...even when there's never and exception?

Answer (score 7):

It's bad practice to use exception handling for implementing your business logic. Exception handling is for handling exceptional cases.

In your specific example it is even clearer that using exception handling is wrong, since your are duplicating your code in the exception handler.

BTW, your method has another potential problem. You have no guarantee that in each call to `add` you'll receive an array of the same length, so you run the risk of ignoring some of the values passed to your method, or getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if `vec` is shorter than `running_sum`.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning `Optional.computeIfAbsent`.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime exceptions like `NullPointerException` or `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` are an indicator of a bug in your program because you as the developer screwed up. Not the user or some external factor but *your* code.

You should never try to catch them, you have to make sure they simply cannot occur. If they occur, track them down and fix your code to make sure they never occur again.

If `running_sum` must not be null, enforce that by adding a constructor, that takes the value as parameter and checks for non-null. Having a `add` method without anything to add the input to makes no sense.